# Google Forms Submission Page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, google-forms

I'm working on a form that is sending data to a Google Spreadsheet.

I created a form under Google Forms, and viewed the live form when I was done. Following that, I viewed source and took the HTML code needed to send the data to the spreadsheet accordingly. I did it like this so I did not get the ugly body template Google offered, and customized it at free will. I cannot figure out how to drop the confirmation page, or redirect around it.

I tried using JavaScript redirection methods. I can close the window with the data submitted before anyone sees the confirmation page, but I just want it to go to an alternative page when the data is complete.

Any help is appreciated- thank you!

Comment: If i understood well you are trying to create a custom form using the HTML code from Google Forms to send data to your Google Doc Spreadsheet. Have you checked this [link](https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000) ? After a Success message you can have better control of the redirection.

Comment: This may be what I am looking for, but I'll have to poke around this a little more. This would be my first "big" AJAX project, so I will definitely look into this for the future. Thanks @JoãoMartins!

Comment: I was trying... I am unsure how to upvote on this newer version of Stack Overflow. Can you tell me how please? Thanks!

Comment: when you hover your mouse over the comment it will appear a flag and a up arrow on the left corner of the comment. Try it !

Comment: It does not let me on my opening question... I don't get any next to comments.

Comment: Then i will paste as an answer so you can upvote and mark it as answered, fair

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understood well you are trying to create a custom form using the HTML code from Google Forms to send data to your Google Doc Spreadsheet. Have you checked this [Link](https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000) ? After a Success message you can have better control of the redirection.

Comment: This may be what I am looking for, but I'll have to poke around this a little more. This would be my first "big" AJAX project, so I will definitely look into this for future projects. Thank you very much @JoãoMartins!

Comment: This almost a link only answer. Please include the relevant parts of the referred web page.